# Google Chrome: "The application failed to initialize properly"

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome

Google Chrome stopped working for me today.

When I launch Chrome, I see the following error:

[image: The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click OK to terminate the application.]

> Windows - Application Error
>   The application failed to initialize
>   properly (0xc0000135). Click OK to
>   terminate the application.

It fails to load the New Tab Page.

After a moment, I see the following error:

[image: The following page(s) have become unresponsive. You can wait for them to become responsive or kill them.]

> Google Chrome
>   The following page(s) have become
>   unresponsive. You can wait for them to
>   become responsive or kill them.

My operating system is Microsoft Windows Vista.

### I've tried:

1. uninstalled Chrome
2. rebooted
3. reinstalled Chrome
4. rebooted

That didn't fix it.

### What now?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What changed between yesterday and today?

Try an offline installer and use the latest dev build, maybe it can solve the problem. [Here's](http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/408.1/chrome_installer.exe) a direct link for the installer of the latest dev build of Chrome (6.0.408.1). This might seem strange, but I had problems with Gears, one of the plugins that Chrome has; I was able to start Chrome but when I went to a page that had support for Gears (Gmail, for instance), it crashed. The solution to that was disabling Gears (from about:plugins).

Comment: As far as I know, nothing changed besides perhaps an automatic Windows update.

Comment: @Zack Peterson the update had nothing to do with Chrome, from what I can tell. Have you tried the latest dev build?

Answer (score 1):

Install .net framework from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Chrome profile might be corrupted.  I have had similar errors before but I guess that's what I get for being on the Dev branch.

1. Navigate to the folder `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
2. Rename the folder `Default` to `Default.old`
3. Open Chrome.

If you really want to, you can close Chrome again and copy the files into from Default.old folder back into the Default folder one by one until you find the culprit.  Most likely an extension or something funky behind the scenes, if you are using extensions that is.  The important files you will want to copy across are Bookmarks, Cookies and History for example.